# How does one iterate through an object's property values in order to verify for some values (objects as well) each another specific property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, conditional-statements

So I am trying to iterate through an object to see if it has a specific "id" key. I've tried `hasOwnProperty()`, .includes, and "if 'id' in item". I've also just tried to check the actual length of the object, but still not working. I do not know why none of these options have worked.

In this image I've tried to count the number of keys in the `flightsbyId` object. All it does is return the number of characters in the item not the number of objects in the parent object.

[image]

Look at the console. It says false for all of the objects, however all except one have a key that is an id.
[image]

[image]

Ex object:

```
const formik = {
  randomObj: "something",
  values: {
    flight1: { name: "flight1", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497984 },
    flight2: { name: "flight2", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497982 },
    flight3: { name: "flight3", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497989 },
    flight4: { name: "flight4", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497981 },
  },
  attributes: null,
};
```

What I expect written as pseudo code:

```
if 'id' in flight1, console.log(true), else console.log(false)
```

OR

```
if length(flight1)=== a number, return true
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: So you have an object of objects and you want the id only? Pls also share  a sample of your object. You don't need to post the real data, you can replace it with some dummy values, but if you want an answer, you should to provide code, not screenshots

Comment: @J_K okay will add sample

Comment: @Win I want the number of items in one key(flight1). In one flight, there should be 19 keys(attributes, name, id). Or alternatively I just want to verify if a flight has the "id" object.

Comment: @Win okay added further info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to look for a specific id. I consoled the object found and the length of that specific object. But I am being very unclear with what exactly you want.

```js
let formik = {
  "randomObj": 'something',
  "values": {
    flight1: {
      'name': "flight1",
      'timecreated': "sometime",
      id: 548497984
    },
    flight2: {
      'name': "flight2",
      'timecreated': "sometime",
      id: 548497982
    },
    flight3: {
      'name': "flight3",
      'timecreated': "sometime",
      id: 548497989
    },
    flight4: {
      'name': "flight4",
      'timecreated': "sometime",
      id: 548497981
    }
  },
  attributes: 'null'
}

for (let key in formik.values) {
  if (formik.values[key].id === 548497984) {
    console.log(formik.values[key])
    console.log("Length is: ", Object.keys(formik.values[key]).length)
    break;
  } else {
    console.log("no matches")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) are the methods of choice for getting a boolean result/answer when operating a list of data items.

Additionally should be mentioned that both methods exit an array's iteration early which means as soon as either an `every` condition fails or as soon as a `some` condition does match.

```js
const formik = {
  randomObj: "something",
  values: {
    flight1: { name: "flight1", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497984 },
    flight2: { name: "flight2", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497982 },
    flight3: { name: "flight3", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497989 },
    flight4: { name: "flight4", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497981 },
  },
  attributes: null,
};

console.log(
  '... does flight with `id: 548497989` exist ?..',
  Object
    .values(formik.values)
    .some(({ id }) => id === 548497989)
)
console.log(
  '... does flight with `id: 123456789` exist ?..',
  Object
    .values(formik.values)
    .some(({ id }) => id === 123456789)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

And in case the OP wants to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) a `flight` item by its `id` then the above provided code needs to be changed only by its method names.

Thus the only difference in between `some` and `find` is the return value `true`/`false` for the former and the `undefined` value or the matching array item for the latter.

```js
const formik = {
  randomObj: "something",
  values: {
    flight1: { name: "flight1", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497984 },
    flight2: { name: "flight2", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497982 },
    flight3: { name: "flight3", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497989 },
    flight4: { name: "flight4", timecreated: "sometime", id: 548497981 },
  },
  attributes: null,
};

console.log(
  '... find flight with `id: 548497989` ...',
  Object
    .values(formik.values)
    .find(({ id }) => id === 548497989)
);
console.log(
  '... find flight with `id: 123456789` ...',
  Object
    .values(formik.values)
    .find(({ id }) => id === 123456789)
);

console.log(
  '... how many properties has flight with `id: 548497989` ?..',
  Object.keys(

    Object
    .values(formik.values)
    .find(({ id }) => id === 548497989) ?? {}

  ).length || null // || -1 // || 'none'
);
console.log(
  '... how many properties has flight with `id: 123456789` ?..',
  Object.keys(

    Object
    .values(formik.values)
    .find(({ id }) => id === 123456789) ?? {}

  ).length || null // || -1 // || 'none'
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const idsOrLength = Object.keys(formik.values.flightsById).map(({ itemKey }) => {
      const item = formik.values.flightsById[itemKey];
      const { id } = item;
      const length = Object.keys(item).length

      return id || length;
});
```

Comment: if you Nested - implies recursion... no?

Comment: are you saying I should put this code within the for loop or in replacement of the for loop?

Comment: Replacement for ur loop

Comment: @Gorynych what if I just wanted to console log this? Wouldn't a return statement just give me one result? What would the return look like?

Comment: If I correctly understood you, @ColorfulCodes, you ned to loop through the object of objects and return item id or items keys length. Thats what the fucntion does. I'm going to fix the code do that you could console.log the const

Comment: @Gorynych actually no, I just was to see if the key "id" exists, not return the actual key itself. or return the entire length the a specific flight. For example, all flights except new ones should contain 19 objects. Sorry for confusion.